# Open street map server with correct India Map

Tags: openstreetmap

Due to statutory requirements, we need to create our own open street map server with correct India map which includes the disputed boundaries. I have already installed OSM server using the instructions given in the following link:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04#comment-13257

I also have the correct shape files but I am not able to render the correct maps. I can still see disputed regions not part of India.

any body have any experience, kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to correct the India maps on my own tile server. For details please find the link below:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/azaadshatru/diary/390300

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you already know about the [OpenStreetMap India](https://openstreetmap.in) project? You can get more information about it at [their GitHub project](https://github.com/osm-in/openstreetmap.in) or via the [talk-in mailing list](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-in). For personal projects you can also use their tile server.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I know about OSM India but due to some restrictions, our organization need to build our own Map Server . My server is installed and working but I am not able to render the correct map of India